# Can I adopt a loose container in a new docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have several loose containers, including for example a rabbitmq container, that I am using for development. I have started migrating all of these loose containers to a docker-compose file for easier management and spinning up/down when testing. Unfortunately, there is a lot of configuration in these containers that I would rather not have to spend time setting up again.

As such, I was wondering if it was possible to adopt a docker container into a new docker-compose file.

I tried starting the compose file with just using the same name as the loose container, but I get `cannot create container for service rabbitmq: Conflict. The container name "/rabbitmq" is already in use by container "<ID>". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name`

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely add a container that you used to start with `docker run` to a docker-compose file. Your issue seems to be that you're naming the container the same as the running rabbitmq container, and you can't have two containers running with the same name. If you remove the running container, you should be able to start it again using docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that when you run *"docker compose"* it will not start a new container if there is one already running with that name and it will just reuse that, it doesn't work that way.

You should define any configurations that you used when running the stand-alone container in your docker-compose file.

Comment: My goal was to reuse the data from the old container. Not take over a live container.